# Increment Counter DTO object properties across multiple services in a java application?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a java application that has a main class and multiple services, DAOs and DTOs. This is a java project that uses JDBC for DAOs. I am not using spring or anything else.

For example the Counter DTO object is:

```
public class CountDTO{
    private int passengers;
    private int repairs;
    private int miles;
    private int errors;

    //getters & setters ....

}
```

Main class :

```
public class Taxi(){
    public static void main(String[] args){

        CountDTO countDTO = new CountDTO();

        if(noCarAvailable()){
            countDTO.setErrors(countDTO.getErrors()++); //DOING INCREMENT HERE
        }else(){
            TaxiService taxiService = new TaxiServiceImpl();
            taxiService.start();
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, in the main class I want to increment the number of errors when no car found.

Similarly, in one of the service classes I need to increment and decrement number of passengers.

And may be in another service I need to keep incrementing total MILES travelled, to know how many miles the taxi travelled before the end of main class.

So MY QUESTION IS, how can I preserve the counts (CounterDTO int property values) to send an email with these count values?
And I don't want to initialize the CountDTO in main class and pass it as a parameter to all the service methods where ever I need to increment it's property values.

Comment: if I undestand you right, you might just make the field static. but I would definitely created a separate singleton class collecting statistics for that

Answer (score 1):

You could turn CountDTO into a singleton if you'll only ever have the 1 instance:

```
public class CountDTO {

    private static final CountDTO instance = new CountDTO();

    public static CountDTO getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private CountDTO() {}

    ...
}
```

If you're going to be accessing the values from different services concurrently, you will also want to mark the variables in `CountDTO`  as `volatile`.